# Customize the request to get data from another URL resources

Tags: asp.net

The situation is as follows: a CMS system (close source) doesn't use friendly URLs in the manner that we want. It add sub-maps and a static .aspx file and we don't that. Example: the CMS recognizes this: /public/submap/bla/page.aspx?id=CONTACT (page 'contact' in this example). But we want friendly URsL for this page like this: **/contact**.

My goal: before the CMS engine renders the page, that an incoming request (/contact) will change to the CMS recognized URL (/public/submap/bla/page.aspx?id=CONTACT) but the browser doesn't see this.

I've tried this on some pages with HTTPModule (interface IHttpModule, event BeginRequest) but the only possible way is to redirect 300 to the browser (it will recevied '/contact' and do a redirect to /public/.../page.aspx?id=CONTACT which the browser address toolbar shows).

It there a manner to 'fake' the CMS engine that will recognized it's own URL but between browser and ASP.NET an another URL?

Environment: IIS6 (Windows 2003) and .NET Framework 3.5/4.0.

Comment: Please post the version of .NET and IIS that you are using as different options are available.

Comment: I'm trying Server.Transfer(). It look that this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server.tranfer is the solution.

Comment: Another solution: use Webclient to read the CMS HTML data. Set before type POST/Get, cookies and optional post data.